# Как (если возможно) реализовать такое меню только на CSS (без JS)?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Можно ли без использования js создать такое меню? пока в голову приходит только абсолютное позиционирование и сдвиг на нное количество пикселей вверх/вниз с помощью jquery, который не очень хотелось использовать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd: в итоге сделал с jquery что-то похожее, если кому-то понадобится рабочий код:

```js
/*
приминает: id элемента, сдвиг в пикселях, у меня с двух сторон слайдеры, по этому сторону слайдера
*/
function carousel(id, topPl, side) {
  var p1 = 'calc(50% - ' + topPl + 'px)';
  $('#' + side + '-checker').css('top', p1);
  $('#' + side + '-' + id).siblings().css('opacity', 0.3);
  $('#' + side + '-' + id).css('opacity', 1);
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* Carousels */

.carousel {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.carousel ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: calc(50% - 280px);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
}

.carousel li {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
}

#left-carousel {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#left-carousel #choise {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: 325px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel" id="left-carousel">
  <ul id="left-checker">
    <li id="left-1" onclick="carousel(1,40,'left')">text</li>
    <li id="left-2" onclick="carousel(2,120,'left')">text</li>
    <li id="left-3" onclick="carousel(3,200,'left')">text</li>
    <li id="left-4" onclick="carousel(4,280,'left')">text</li>
    <li id="left-5" onclick="carousel(5,360,'left')">text</li>
    <li id="left-6" onclick="carousel(6,440,'left')">text</li>
    <li id="left-7" onclick="carousel(7,520,'left')">text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Каков принцип действия этого меню? Мне кажется вполне реально

Comment: @koks_rs, есть ul, при щелке на li - он становится по центру родительского div, сдвигая вверх/вниз весь ul

Comment: Насколько я помню, в Скайриме при выборе (к примеру, от текущего на фотке) элемента списка, другие перемещаются выше или ниже, делая выбранный элемент по центру. Увы, так css не может! Но не расстраивайся. Скрипт не так уж сложен будет в реализации.

Comment: @VostokSisters, вы правильно помните)

Comment: @nueq, вот [это](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/egjWKy) максимум, что я видел, делали выборочное меню через чистый css. Можешь на codepen сам поискать через запрос "selective menu".

Comment: Вынесите своё решение в ответ лучше.

Comment: @D-side, оно не соответствует поставленному вопросу без js у меня все-таки не удалось реализовать такое меню. Поэтому это не совсем ответ

Comment: @nueq, да думаю, всё равно ваш код как ответ будет лучше смотреться. Мне так кажется...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Придумал метод еще проще:

Надо разместить скрытые `radio` выше на элемент. А сами кнопки сделать `label` c сылками на эти `radio`

При нажатии на `label` активируются `radio`, которые сдвигают блок с меню.

```css
input { display:none }
#items{
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  transition: top .5s;
}
#items label{
  display:block;
  height:25px;
}

#p1:checked~#items{top:50px;}
#p2:checked~#items{top:25px;}
#p3:checked~#items{top:0px;}
#p4:checked~#items{top:-25px;}
#p5:checked~#items{top:-50px;}

#active{
 border:1px solid red;
 top:50px;
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 height:25px;
}
```

```html
<input type=radio id="p1" name="menu">
<input type=radio id="p2" name="menu">
<input type=radio id="p3" name="menu">
<input type=radio id="p4" name="menu">
<input type=radio id="p5" name="menu">

<div id="items">

    <label for="p1">Пункт 1</label>
    <label for="p2">Пункт 2</label> 
    <label for="p3">Пункт 3</label> 
    <label for="p4">Пункт 4</label> 
    <label for="p5">Пункт 5</label> 
    
</div>

<div id="active"></div>
```

Comment: вместо radio, можно селектор [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:target) попробовать использовать. Хотя не, в текущем случае может не помочь :-)

Comment: @Grundy c `:target` есть решение

Comment: Ага, просмотрел его :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ради интереса попытался реализовать, вот что получилось

```css
.invisible { display: none; }
.checker { margin-top: 150px; }
.checker a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;

    transition: top 0.3s;
    top: 0px;
}

/* смещения, можно генерировать каким-нибудь scss */
.checker #p1:target ~ a { top: 0px; }
.checker #p2:target ~ a { top: -25px; }
.checker #p3:target ~ a { top: -50px; }
.checker #p4:target ~ a { top: -75px; }
.checker #p5:target ~ a { top: -100px; }
.checker #p6:target ~ a { top: -125px; }
.checker #p7:target ~ a { top: -150px; }
```

```html
<nav class="checker">
    <!-- элементы-приманки -->
    <div class="invisible" id="p1"></div>
    <div class="invisible" id="p2"></div>
    <div class="invisible" id="p3"></div>
    <div class="invisible" id="p4"></div>
    <div class="invisible" id="p5"></div>
    <div class="invisible" id="p6"></div>
    <div class="invisible" id="p7"></div>
    
    <!-- узлы меню -->
    <a href="#p1">Пункт 1</a>
    <a href="#p2">Пункт 2</a>
    <a href="#p3">Пункт 3</a>
    <a href="#p4">Пункт 4</a>
    <a href="#p5">Пункт 5</a>
    <a href="#p6">Пункт 6</a>
    <a href="#p7">Пункт 7</a>
</nav>
```

Основная идея: сделать целевым какой-нибудь элемент (из *семи* похожих) и подобрать селектор как-нибудь так, чтобы стили применились ко всем пунктам меню.
Теоретически, пример можно даже улучшить, переместив «приманки» на уровень выше, чтоб семантика особо не страдала.

Answer (score 0):

Или же можно использовать при наведении такой метод сss 3 как hover. В итоге получится что-то типа такого

```
menu_label{
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    left: 0%;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
menu_label:hover{
    opacity:1;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Думаю можно доделать,но сейчас нет возможности протестить этот код.

```
<menu_label>menu 1</menu_label>
<menu_label>menu 2</menu_label>
<menu_label>menu 3</menu_label>
```